# Unable to find an entry point named 'rd_kafka_producev' in shared library 'librdkafka'

Tags: linux, docker, apache-kafka

I'm working on a .NET Core application that uses the Nuget package - Confluent.Kafka, Version 0.11.3

I'm using it to instantiate a `Producer`, then calling the `myProducer.ProduceAsync` method. I get an error in the application logs stating - `Unable to find an entry point named 'rd_kafka_producev' in shared library 'librdkafka'`.

I'm running Kafka in a container running on Debian v9. The docker container that's running the .NET Core application that uses Kafka has `librdkafka1 - v0.9.3-1` installed. I needed to manually install it in the container as part of the Docker image, using:

`RUN apt-get update -y`
`RUN apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev`

I don't understand why I needed to install it manually anyway - this was to fix an error where the library wasn't being found at all. Shouldn't it already exist on the image? I'm using the standard `wurstmeister/kafka` Docker image.

Everything is working on a different server, where the exact same Confluent.Kafka package version is being used, and the exact same `librdkafka1` is installed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I removed this from the Docker file:

`RUN apt-get update -y`
`RUN apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev`

Then, deleted `librdkafka1` from the Debian container running my application. Redeployed my application to the container and now it works. The strange thing is, `librdkafka1` now doesn't exist as a package on the container.

I found out that the `librdkafka1` is a C++ library needed by the .NET Confluent.Kafka dependency within my .NET Core project. I also raised this [Github issue](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/2720), and Magnus Edenhill, the creator of librdkafka kindly provided this info:

> confluent-kafka-dotnet depends on the librdkafka.redist nuget package
>   which contains librdkafka, so you typically don't have to manually
>   install librdkafka on the system (there are some cases where you
>   might, such as when using GSSAPI).

So in most cases, as long as you have the Confluent.Kafka nuget package as a dependency in your solution, `librdkafka` should be installed somehow. So if you're getting similar issues to mine, it may be worth clearing out your deployment/container and any explicitly installed instances of `librdkafka1`, and redeploying to install the dependencies.